# Start Google MapView at a default location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been searching for a way to start Google `MapView` at a default location and zoom level, and can't seem to find it. Is there a way to do this, or does it have to start zoomed out looking at the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `Intent` with action `VIEW` and one of these URIs:

- geo:latitude,longitude
- geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
- geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
- geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

See [*Common Intents*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) for details.